# How to change results in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table, we'll call it users.

```
id username type
```

The type field is a two character type, so each user either has US, MO, AD.  Not sure why the original developer did this, but I cannot change this method, unfortunately.

```
1 mike US
2 Tim AD
3 mark MO
```

Instead of returning US, AD... etc types in Access, I'd like the query to replace the US with USER, replace MO with MODERATOR, and replace AD with ADMIN.

Is this possible?

Kind of like SELECT * FROM USERS and then if statements within Access (if US, then USER).  Not sure how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table for the US to USER, MO to MODERATOR etc mappings and use it in a join.
A lot easier to maintain, extend (i.e. different languages) than hard-coding with the drawback that you need to maintain your mapping table.

Comment: I always over think these simple things.

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing!  Try something along these lines:
select [id], [username], 
iif([type] = "US", "User",
  iif([type] = "MO", "Moderator",
    iif([type] = "AD", "Admin", "Unknown Type"
  )
)

(Here's a link to the [IIf](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) function)

All things considered, though, you may want to normalize your data with a lookup table.  So, for example, create a second table called, "UserType" with two columns: [Code] and [Name].  Then populate it with three records:
"US", "User"
"MO", "Moderator"
"AD", "Admin"

Then, within query designer, include both tables and join them by dragging the "type" column from your source table to the "[Code]" column on the [UserType] table.  Then, select the [id] and [username] columns from the first table, and the [name] column from the lookup table.  That way, if you need to add new user types, you don't have to worry about going back and modifying all of your queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you had another table called user type that looked like this

```
UserType (typeid, description) 
US  USER 
AD  ADMIN 
MO  MODERATOR
```

it would be trivial

```
 SELECT users.id, users.username, UserType.description as type
 FROM 
    USERS 
    INNER JOIN UserType
    ON USERS.Type = UserType.TypeID;
```

you could also use a VBA function, or nested IIF

You could also change your Look up Display Control to a Combo Box and set the row source type to value list

Comment: Probably updating the table could be easier or adding description column to the table if he is going to deal it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server has a construct called [Case When](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) but it's not available in MS Access.

Here is a [workaround](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/02/adding_case_to_.html)

Comment: Er, the workaround seems to me re-implement a function that already exists, Switch(). Of course, CASE WHEN and Switch() always verge on storing data in your SQL statements, so if you are tempted to use them, you should ask yourself whether or not the data pairs involved should maybe be stored in a table, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should have a table for this -- anything else verges on storing data in your SQL statements.

For completeness, let me mention Switch() and Choose(). The former takes an arbitrary number of value pairs, the latter takes an index and a list of values. The former works for strings or numbers, as with CASE WHEN, while Choose() works only with numbers.

Both are of limited utility, since use of them amounts to storing a lookup table in your SQL, but it's good to know about these things for cases where it's simply not feasible to add a lookup table.